# Videos exported in H264 from Adobe products have huge audio delay and sync issues

Tags: adobe

When I export a H264 video from Adobe Premiere and try to play it on MacOS Monterey version 12, if I scrub the video or move the playhead at all, audio and video desync.

Lots of people have the issue as can be seen here.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252680507

Haven't seen any solutions yet.

Anyone know how to fix this?